# GotJS - get both response attributes and JSON body

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-got

I want to check that my endpoint returns the 404 error status and that the body has some property. GotJS support JSON mode which automatically parses body but I do not have HTTP attributes then. Can I combine it somehow? Or do I need to parse JSON myself? I especially do not understand that the method `json()` once works and then is undefined.

Test

```
data = await bff("polls/abc").json();
console.log(data);
console.log(data.success);
response = await bff("polls/abc");
console.log(response.body);
console.log(response.json());
```

Output

```
console.log test/polls.int.test.js:96
{ success: false }

console.log test/polls.int.test.js:97
false

console.log test/polls.int.test.js:99
{"success":false}

TypeError: response.json is not a function
```

Why are not these two variants equivalent?

```
await bff("polls/abc").json()
```

and

```
response = await bff("polls/abc");
response.json();
```

Update: bff definition

```
const bff = got.extend({
    prefixUrl: "http://localhost:3000/bff/",
    throwHttpErrors: false,
    headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8'"
    },
});
```

Cengel's solution

```
response = await bff("polls/abc", { responseType: 'json' });
console.log(response.body.success);
console.log(response.statusCode);

console.log test/polls.int.test.js:98
false

console.log test/polls.int.test.js:99
404
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do

```
response = await bff("polls/abc");
response.json();
```

because the `json()` function is an asynchronous function, just like `bff`, and it returns a promise and must be awaited as well.

To understand why the call `await bff("polls/abc").json()` works, we have to dissect it. First of all, the `await` is *not* awaiting `bff("polls/abc")` (which returns a Promise) but the call to `json()`.

But wait: if `bff()` returns a Promise, why does `bff().json()` work? Shouldn't `bff()` have to be awaited first?

A line in the `got` documentation may deliver the answer:

> The promise also has .text(), .json() and .buffer() methods which return another Got promise for the parsed body.

So the Promise returned by `bff()` is not actually a "true" Promise but has these three convenience methods so you *don't* have to await `bff()` too if you're only getting its response as JSON. But since you *do* actually want to look at the response itself as well, you should do the following instead:

```
const promise = bff("polls/abc");
const response = await promise;
const data = await promise.json();

if (response.status === 404) {
   ...
}
```

Another way seems to be to set the `responseType` to "json", which should automatically convert the body to JSON, so you don't have to call `json()` manually at all and can just use:

```
const response = await bff("polls/abc", { responseType: 'json' });

if (response.status === 404) {
   // use response.body to access the converted json
}
```

Comment: I have added bff definition. Sorry I overlooked it. bff == got with some parameters. Got returns NodeJS response.

Comment: No problem! I updated my answer. There may be a better solution (for instance, you could try setting responseType: 'json' in your `bff` function), but if I am reading the GotJS documentation right, my answer *should* work.